# Is it possible to get the two values from conditional(ternary) operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have the following javascript code, with the two values.

```
var w = $("#id1").val();
var h = $("#id2").val();  
(w == h) ? (w=350 , h=350):((w<h)?(w=300 , h=350):(w=350 , h=300));
```

Here i want to check the three conditions.

```
1) If w == h then we need to assign some values.  
2)else if w < h then we need to assign some other values.    
3)else if w > h then we need to assign some other values.
```

above code is showing not giving the w and values showing javascript error, how to get those values with the ternary operator, with out using if and else conditions.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: technically we can't. If you want it concise, you can try another way depending on the actual case.

Comment: Nope, not directly. But let's be honest, do you think that's readable (or concise)?

Comment: Not exactly related, but you might get unexpected results when comparing two strings, it's better to convert `w` and `h` to numbers before comparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can return an array (alternatively an object) from the conditional operator, and assign values from the array:

```
var values = w == h ? [350, 350] : w < h ? [300, 350] : [350, 300];
w = values[0];
h = values[1];
```

---

Your original code should actually work, it does when I test it. However, you are misusing the conditional operator. If you want to do the assignment directly and not return a value, you should not use the conditional operator, but just an `if` statement:

```
if (w == h) {
  w = 350; h = 350;
} else if (w < h) {
  w = 300; h = 350;
} else {
  w = 350; h = 300;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (which is longer) is by using closure and immediately executed function:

```
w == h ? function(){w = 350; h = 350}() : 
w < h ? function(){w = 300; h = 350}() : 
        function(){w = 350; h = 300}();
```